# Cannot locally serve jekyll using existing site

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I recently had to factory reset my computer. I redownloaded the repo for my Github Pages site, and reinstalled `ruby`, `jekyll`, and `bundler` following the [Quickstart](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/) directions.

I am able to push new blog posts to my github repo without issue. However, I would also like to run the posts locally before publishing them. But when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` I get the following output:

```
⠠⠵ bundle exec jekyll serve
/Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:29: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
/Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
/Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
/Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:35: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
/Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:35: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
/Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:44: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
/Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/bin/jekyll)
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rexml/parsers/baseparser
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/kramdown-1.13.2/lib/kramdown/parser/html.rb:10:in `require'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/kramdown-1.13.2/lib/kramdown/parser/html.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/kramdown-1.13.2/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/html.rb:10:in `require'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/kramdown-1.13.2/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/html.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/kramdown-1.13.2/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/paragraph.rb:14:in `require'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/kramdown-1.13.2/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/paragraph.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/kramdown-1.13.2/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:342:in `require'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/kramdown-1.13.2/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:342:in `<class:Kramdown>'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/kramdown-1.13.2/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:60:in `<module:Parser>'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/kramdown-1.13.2/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:19:in `<module:Kramdown>'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/kramdown-1.13.2/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/smartypants.rb:1:in `require'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/smartypants.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll.rb:11:in `require'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll.rb:11:in `block in require_all'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll.rb:10:in `each'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll.rb:10:in `require_all'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll.rb:186:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/exe/jekyll:6:in `require'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/exe/jekyll:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/bin/jekyll:25:in `load'
  /Users/adamg/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/bin/jekyll:25:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have added `webrick`, so I don't believe that is the issue. I also didn't run a `jekyll new [myblog]` during the setup since I already have a blog. I am thinking that maybe there is a clash between my pre-existing files and the newly install `ruby` and `jekyll`, but I'm not sure how to check. Here is my `Gemfile`. Do I need to modify this? I also tried removing the version number from `webrick`.:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "github-pages", '163', group: :jekyll_plugins

# enable tzinfo-data for local build
# gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
gem 'jekyll-paginate'

# gem "webrick", "~> 1.8"
gem "webrick"
```

Comment: I'm facing a very similar problem. Looking at [this issue](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/752) there appear to be **lots** of different dependency problems with Jekyll when used with gh-pages. In my case adding `webrick` and re-running `bundle install` solved the problem, but in your case I see it didn't. From the logs it appears you also miss `baseparser` as a dependency, so try installing that. Also, in my case, adding `--livereload` for some reason breaks everything, so I'm omitting that option. Hope I helped a little bit.

Comment: I think the issue might be related to the version of github-pages in your gemfile. It seems outdated compared to what is used on github.com. you can see currently used dependencies here: https://pages.github.com/versions/ at the time of writing the current version is 231. Can you try that followed by a bundle install?